# Finding the modulus of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, exponential-function

Let $\gamma$ be the path$$\gamma:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}, t\rightarrow\exp\left(t+it\right)$$

I have found that $$\gamma'\left(t\right)=\left(1+i\right)\exp\left(t+it\right)$$

To find the length of this path, I need to find $\left|\gamma'\left(t\right)\right|$ but I'm not sure how to find the modulus.

I understand $\left|x+iy\right|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ but I don't know how to apply this to this paticular function.

Answer (score 0):

Use that

$$\exp (z) = \exp (\Re z)(\cos (\Im z) +i\sin (\Im z)).$$